Element implicitly has an 'any' type. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'User1'
I tried using computed properties in TypeScript, but I'm getting the following error:
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'User1'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'User1'

Code:
type User1 = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  address: string;
};

const user1: User1 = {
  name: "user1",
  age: 23,
  address: "address",
};

let checkParameter: string | number = "name";
console.log(user1[checkParameter]); //error occurring here

checkParameter = "age";
console.log(user1[checkParameter]); //error occurring here

checkParameter = "address";
console.log(user1[checkParameter]); //error occurring here

The checkParameter is random and will be decided at runtime.
I'm expecting error free execution.

Is checkParameter random, or will it be explicitly "name", "age", or "address"? It seems like you are typing the value you are expecting to access rather than the key.

string | number is not a type that TypeScript can use to track what values you've assigned. If all you know is that checkParameter is a string, TS considers it a mistake to use it as an index to User1. I'd say with this code you should annotate it as keyof User as shown in this playground link. If that meets your needs, I (or maybe @uncle_baby_kern) could write up an answer explaining; if not, please [edit] to make your code a [mre] where that wouldn't suffice.

You can add [key: string]: string to specify that the type User1 has properties with keys of type string
type User1  = {
   [key: string]: string;
   name: string;
   age: number;
   address: string;
};

const user1: User1 = {
   name: "user1",
   age: 23,
   address: "address",
};

let checkParameter: string | number = "name";
console.log(user1[checkParameter]);

Since checkParameter has two types string | number and it refers to a key, if the User1 type will have a key of type number, add this type to the key:
type User1  = {
   [key: string | number]: string
   name: string;
   age: number;
   address: string;
};


You didn't add {[k: string]: string}, you added {[k: string]: any}.

One solution is to change the type for checkParameter to a union of the strings representing each property.
let checkParameter: name" | "age" | "address" = "name"
Update: As @jcalz suggested, keyof User1 would dynamically represent the User1 properties:
type User1 = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  address: string;
};

const user1: User1 = {
  name: "User 1",
  age: 23,
  address: "123 First St",
};

let checkParameter: keyof User1 = "name";
console.log(user1[checkParameter]); // User 1

checkParameter = "age";
console.log(user1[checkParameter]); // 23

checkParameter = "address";
console.log(user1[checkParameter]); // 123 First St

